# Need to create a new variable based on specific Condition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

#I am using below code#

```
for i in test.construction:
     if i.find("Wood"):
         test["Category"]="tree"

print (test[["construction", "Category"]])
```

OUTPUT:
construction Category

```
            Masonry     tree
            Masonry     tree
               Wood     tree
               Wood     tree
```

I'm using `find` and not `'=='` because it could contain multiple words/string in Construction column.
It's giving `"tree"` every time.
I want `Category="Mason"` when `construction= "Masonry"`

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition created by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) if need `tree` and if condition fail `mason`:

```
test['Category'] = np.where(test['construction'].str.contains('Wood'), 'tree', 'mason')
print (test)
  construction Category
0      Masonry    mason
1      Masonry    mason
2         Wood     tree
3         Wood     tree
```

Or if many conditions is possible use custom function with in for test substrings:

```
def f(x):
    if 'Wood' in x:
        return 'tree'
    elif 'Masonry' in x:
        return 'mason'
    else:
        return x

test['Category'] = test['construction'].apply(f)
```

Comment: @Sandy - Do you want test substrings?